# How to dynamically add a PDO statement into array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

How do I dynamically add a PDO statement into array?
I would like write a function as in example:

```
function executePreparedQRY($QueryString, $ArrayParams, $UseBufferedQry = FALSE) {
    if ($UseBufferedQry) {
        $ArrayParams[] = PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY;
    }
    return $statement = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()->prepare($QueryString)->execute($ArrayParams);
}
```

But `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` is always understood as another query param, not as a PDO statement.
So, how do I include `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` in the execute statement depending on `$UseBufferedQry` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you should use this in `prepare`, not in `execute`.

```
return $statement = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()
    ->prepare($QueryString, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true))
    ->execute($ArrayParams);
```

[`PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo.constants.mysql-attr-use-buffered-query)

So for your purposes, you could do something like:

```
$PrepareParams=array();
if ($UseBufferedQry) {
    $PrepareParams[PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY] = true;
}

return $statement = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter()
    ->prepare($QueryString, $PrepareParams)
    ->execute($ArrayParams);
```

Comment: I'm terribly sorry if asking a lame questions I'm not skilled in php as you can see, but I still have a same err message:
**Message: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens**

This is how I trying to call this function:
**$qry = "insert into test1 (mod2, recomm) values (?, ?)";
  executePreparedQRY($qry, array("a","b"), TRUE);**

Comment: @ bazmegakapa thank you dear sir, everything is clear to me now! :))